# To show date on which highest total price is made in ssrs

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]I have a table with the TotalPrice column and BookedOn column which contains a date in which a particular order was placed. I want to generate a report in SSRS that will show the date on which the highest sales were made.
There are several orders made on a particular date and I want to sum all the price and then compare in which date highest sales were made.

Comment: SSRS? if so then check your DBMS - it should be SQL Server (MS SQL), not MySQL.

Comment: also provide report format and few sample data and expected output

Comment: I don't have a sample output result.  The question is to display the date on which the highest sales amount was achieved.

Comment: is same date have multiple total price in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select top 1  CONVERT(date, BookedOn)  Date, sum(TotalPrice) SumTotalPrice
from your_table_name
group by  BookedOn
order by SumTotalPrice desc

I used convert because didn't know the format of your date column(whether it is datetime or date), you can use just date column otherwise

Comment: Thank you! It is working fine

Comment: Great! would appreciate if you mark it as an answer , would help me improve my reputation  :)

Comment: I have posted one more question. Kindly look into it as well